# Add script into front from my plugin

Tags: plugins, front-end, scripts

I have a WordPress plugin, and I must load scripts from my plugin to the front of the site.

```
class My_Plugin {

function __construct() 
{
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'add_submenu'));

    add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'admin_init'))

}

function load_my_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('script', 'js/myscript.js');
}
```

I would like to load my script, so using the right hook which will be able to add the script into all the page of the site.

I've already tried with

```
add_action('wp_head', array(&$this, 'load_my_scripts'));
add_action('init', array(&$this, 'load_my_scripts'));
```

etc, ... but I don't find any solution... Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `admin_enqueue_scripts` actions to enqueue your scripts:

```
// for front end
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'load_my_scripts'));
// for back end
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'load_my_scripts'));
```

Also pay attention that it is bad practice to load your scripts on all pages of the site. Load your script only if need be:

```
// ...
function load_my_scripts() {
    if ( $some_condition ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('script', 'js/myscript.js');
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: I've also tried this, but I don't understand why my script doesn't load.
It works for the admin, not for the front-end.

Comment: does your theme calls `wp_footer()` function?

Comment: Oh my gosh, thx a lot, I forget to add my_footer(), but it's was wp_head() which make failing.

So I added it and it's work. Thanks a lots !!!

Answer (score 1):

The **most** obvious question is to make sure you have the `wp_head()` tag in your theme header to begin with.

Otherwise straight from the Codex:

```
 <?php
 function my_scripts_method() {
      wp_enqueue_script(
          'custom-script',
          get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
          array('jquery')
      );
 }
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
 ?>
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Load_a_script_from_your_theme_which_depends_upon_a_WordPress_Script

Also double check your paths:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories

Comment: Thx for the long answer, as you said, it's the wp_head() which wasn't here !
Thx for answer !